# How to highlight the the ASP.net grid row on basis of certain value in columns?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a ASP.net Grid i want to change the background color of the row if there particular value like say 5 in one of the column of GRIDview

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to subscribe to the `OnDataBound-Event`.
Afterwards you cast the `e.Row.DataItem` into your custom object (or retrieve the desired values   some other way. depends on your type of datasource)

If your condition matchs, you can set the `BackColor` property of the row individually, by assigning a value to the `e.BackColor` property

I have summed up something similar [here](http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/7/asp.net/gridview-overview-of-different-ways-to-bind-data-to-columns) in the past. (Maybe I'll merge this response in this sometime in the future)

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code:**

```
protected void DrugDetailGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // To check condition on string value 
           //Note: "Drug" is my data Column Name  and "Hydralazine" is value to be match
            if (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Drug")) == "Hydralazine")
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                // Whatever you want to do.......
               // e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            }

            // To check condition on integer value
            if (Convert.ToInt16(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Dosage")) == 50)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
            }
        }
    }
```